# SuspiciousFileOperation at /media/C:/fakepath/example.png when submit from angular

Tags: django, angular, file, upload

I'm building an Angular + Django project, where the user can upload a file to a model:

Model:

```
def upload_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['files', str(instance.titulo), filename])

class File(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=154, null=False, blank=False)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path, null=False)
```

When I send a post request through Insomnia , everything is Ok, the file is saved in the media root(media), but when I send through Angular the path that it saves is similar to the title, and that errors occurs.

Angular:

```
          <div class="row">
            <label style="margin-left: 10px;">Anexos</label>
            <label id="label-input">
              <input [(ngModel)]="ticket.file" type="file" single id="input-file">
            </label>
          </div>
```

Services:

```
htttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json").set('Authorization', this.token);

  public saveNewTicket(ticket): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "ticket/", ticket, {
      headers: this.htttpHeaders
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was sending the data as json, and to send a file or image is required to be in multipart/form-data like this:

HTML:

```
             <form>
                <label id="thumbnail">
                  <input type="file" class="file_selector" (change)=(onFileSelected($event)) />
                </label>
                <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onUpload()" style="float: right;">Salvar Anexo</button>
              </form>
```

TS: Created a **const file**

```
  onFileSelected(e) {
    this.file = e.target.files[0];

  }

  onUpload() {
    this.crudService.updateFile(this.business.id, this.file).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    }, err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
```

crudService.ts: Created the function and instantiate a new Form data, than just append the data

```
  public updateFile(ticketid, file): Observable<any> {
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('id', ticketid);
    body.append('files', file, file.name);
    return this.http.put(this.baseUrl + 'ticket/' + ticketid + '/', body, {
      headers: this.htttpHeadersFormData
    });
  }
```